# Unable to create cloud tasks in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Not really sure where to get support for this or even report it, as basic support requires a monthly subscription.

Trying to set up Cloud Tasks but the page displays the below error:

[image]

Trying to create a queue just leads to the next error:

[image]

I have tried creating a new project and the error persists. The error quite non-descriptive so no clue how to proceed. I'm owner and org admin, so I have god-mode access.

I've also tried going to the APIs dashboard and manually enabling it with no change.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of fiddling I tried to create the task queue via the CLI

```
gcloud tasks queues create <queue name>
```

It then gave me a more informative error, which was that an App Engine app needed to be present first (why?)

```
There is no App Engine app in project [project name].
```

So I created the default App Engine app and was then able to create the queue.

Comment: This document will understand the service: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart